# Foswiki Sidebar Customization

Tags: customization, foswiki

I am new to foswiki, and have it spun up running on a vm at my companies datacenter.

I have most of the baseline config down, but am wondering about some more customization.

Specifically I am looking for some documentation on how to customize the sidebar. Any documentation or tips ya'll hit me back with would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the default theme 'PatternSkin'

One Example of modifying the Sidebar is to change the width:
to do this create a attachment 'SidebarCustomWidth.css' with the following css

```
#patternOuter {
    margin-left: 8em;
}

#patternSideBar {
    width: 8em;
    margin-left: -8em;
    /*background-color: rgb(200, 200, 255);*/
}

/* remove padding */
#patternSideBarContents {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

then you can use it with

```
 * Set USERSTYLEURL = %PUBURLPATH{topic="TheWebname.TopicWithAttachment" "SidebarCustomWidth.css"}%
```

you can find this example at
https://foswiki.org/Sandbox/StefanKr%C3%BCger/PatternSkinCssCookbookSidebarCustomWidth

and some more Documentation and Examples at
https://foswiki.org/System/PatternSkinCssCookbook

Other Options to customize the Content of the Sidebar can be found at
https://foswiki.org/System/PatternSkin#Top_44_Bottom_and_Left_Bar_customization

regarding the Sidebar you can look for `WebLeftBar`.
every web has its own Topic `WebLeftBar`. you can change this to your needs. If a Web has no `WebLeftBar` Topic and no `WebLeftBarExample` Topic (thats the fallback) the Sidebar does not render.
if you want to change the defaults for new webs you can do this in the `_default` web.